# Why onclick function doesnt work inside <div> tag in svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vscode-extensions, svelte

I am developing VS code extension. For that, I used WebView to show user interface and perform some task in it. So that I used svelte to customize my WebView panel.

My problem is, I created svelte file that contain Styles,JS,HTML. So when I call onclick method inside the  tag, it won't work but when it is place out of the  tag it is work. WHY IS THAT HAPPEN?  how can I solve this?

```
<h1 style="text-align:center" on:click={microphoneOnAndOff}>Click Me</h1> **--// This work**

<div class="box">
    <div class="object">
           <div class="outline" style="display: none;"></div>
           <div class="outline" id="delayed" style="display: none;"></div>
           <div class="buttonStyle"></div>
           <div class="buttonStyle" id="circlein">
           <svg  on:click={microphoneOnAndOff} class=""></svg> **--// This Not work**
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the onclick to element in the svg? https://svelte.dev/repl/170a4929993247aba2b16f18621729ab?version=3.23.2

Comment: Or `<div class="buttonStyle" id="circlein" on:click={microphoneOnAndOff}`

Comment: <div class="buttonStyle" id="circlein" on:click={microphoneOnAndOff} this one is also not working. if I place onclick method inside any of <div> tag, it doesn't work  tag@mplungjan. However let me try the first one you provided. Thank you!

Comment: @HirushGimhan Getting the same issue with VS Code Extensions. Did you figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use svg in a tag

```
      <a href="" onclick="clicked"><svg class=""></svg></a> **--// This work** :)
```

Comment: Why not use the div that is wrapping the svg in OP's example?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not work for me! I still try to find a way to solve this.